# MySQL INSERT INTO SELECT statement does not throw TIMEOUT

Tags: mysql

I am using Aurora MySQL version 2.11.

We are conducting tests in MySQL to terminate queries when they run for a long time.

All parameters related to TIMEOUT were set to 10 seconds.

However, TIMEOUT does not seem to be applied in the 'INSERT INTO SELECT' statement.

What should I do to solve this?

```
--------------
SHOW SESSION VARIABLES LIKE '%TIMEOUT%'
--------------

+----------------------------------+----------+
| Variable_name                    | Value    |
+----------------------------------+----------+
| aurora_fwd_master_idle_timeout   | 60       |
| aurora_globaldb_rpo_wait_timeout | 60       |
| connect_timeout                  | 10       |
| delayed_insert_timeout           | 300      |
| have_statement_timeout           | YES      |
| innodb_flush_log_at_timeout      | 1        |
| innodb_lock_wait_timeout         | 10       |
| innodb_rollback_on_timeout       | OFF      |
| interactive_timeout              | 10       |
| lock_wait_timeout                | 10       |
| net_read_timeout                 | 10       |
| net_write_timeout                | 10       |
| rpl_stop_slave_timeout           | 31536000 |
| slave_net_timeout                | 60       |
| wait_timeout                     | 10       |
+----------------------------------+----------+
```

```
MySQL [db_test]> show create table t2;
+-------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            |
+-------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| t2    | CREATE TABLE `t2` (
  `c1` char(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `c2` char(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `c3` char(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `c4` char(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `c5` char(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci |

MySQL [db_test]> select count(*) from t2;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|   131072 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.09 sec)

MySQL [db_test]> show processlist;
+---------+-----------------+----------------------+---------+---------+-------+-----------------------------+---------------------------------+
| Id      | User            | Host                 | db      | Command | Time  | State                       | Info                            |
+---------+-----------------+----------------------+---------+---------+-------+-----------------------------+---------------------------------+
| 3285127 | test_account    | 10.10.10.10:10000    | db_test | Query   |    94 | Sending data                | INSERT INTO T2 SELECT * FROM T2 |
```

Comment: Please have a look at the state column. It says "Sending data" so the insert command is already finished but the server transmits data to the client. Your command already did the job. This means that the insert did not hit the threshold for long running queries.

Comment: I really appreciate your response.
On the client side, the results are not delivered and are waiting. In this situation, if I want to wait for 10 seconds and then stop responding, can you tell me what settings I need?

Comment: For the transmission process there is no timeout. You can terminate that whenever you want. FYI the client displays the result whenever ALL data is transferred.

Comment: thank you I see... If there is no option like timeout, I should create another monitoring session and create logic to monitor whether there is a session that lasts for more than 10 seconds. Have a nice day. thank you

Comment: @ErhardDinhobl, That's not what "sending data" means. It means the query is still executing. Cf. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/general-thread-states.html

Comment: @BillKarwin ah then i missed that. I remember that when i was analyzing that once the sending data is the phase where data is transferred and has nothing todo with reading data and processing it to match the given conditions.

Comment: There is no TIMEOUT for DML queries. Thanks for your help.